# _.isUndefined implementation

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Why is underscore.js's isUndefined defined this way?

`_.isUndefined = function(obj) {
    return obj === void 0;
  };`

Why can't this work?

`typeof obj === 'undefined'`

Comment: `typeof obj === "undefined"` works but strings are ugly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, for a start `typeof obj === 'undefined'` is slower as you can easily verify.

The question then is why make the comparison

```
obj === void 0
```

vs

```
obj === undefined
```

Let's see:

`void 0;` returns the result of the unary operator `void` which will always return `undefined` (i.e. `void 1` would make no difference)

`undefined` points to the global variable `undefined`.

Under normal circumstances the two are the same. I presume though `void 0` is preferred because it is possible to shadow `undefined` with a local variable `undefined` :) This is idiotic but it happens.

Comment: I would like to nuance the "as you can easily verify" part on `typeof obj === 'undefined'` being slower. It is easy to write a microbenchmark that repeats both options a million times and compares the total elapsed time between them. However, such a comparison is almost never meaningful; within the context of a large, real-world application the "faster" option might actually be a pessimization. For reliable information, you need to refactor your actual application so you can compare the options in context, which is not at all easy.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably more efficient the way it's written. Why don't you profile the two definitions and see?

Comment: These results makes sense though.  With typeof and the string comparison you have the extra hashing step to compare equality.

Comment: Perfs also suggest Firefox is doing the same operation internally, or very similar operations. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote `viod`, you'd get a syntax error. You misspelled "undefined" as `'undeifned'`, but you don't get any errors for that. So, one possible reason is easier debugging! :)

Answer (score -1):

As of today (2023-01-23), the lodash implementation (not mine) looks like this:

```
function isUndefined(value) {
  return value === undefined
}
```

I guess this update is due to the fact that `undefined` is read only since ECMAScript 5 and cannot be shadowed anymore.

However, this comes with a problem. If the variable `value` is not defined, e.g. when calling `isUndefined(foo)` the function does not return `true` as you expect. Instead it throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError'

The solution using void 0 has the same problem.

Therefore, using `typeof obj === 'undefined'` is safe.

Comment: Open the developer console of your browser and paste in the definition of `isUndefined` from this answer. Then, on a new line, call the function without arguments: `isUndefined()`. It will return `true`.

Comment: @Julian: The question was why typeof obj === 'undefined' cannot work. I am not promoting the lodash solution. In the contrary, showing a problem with it and conclude that simply 'typeof obj === 'undefined'' instead of a function can be very well used and is safe. The pitfall you mention is a general javascript "feature" or "problem" that you can call a function without passing a parameter although a parameter is expected. It is not related to the original question.

Comment: Yes but I'm telling you that your claim is not true. You wrote that if `value` is not defined, the function will not return `true` as it should. But it does.

Comment: Please open the developer console, paste the function definition, then call `isUndefined(foo)` instead of `isUndefined()`. Verify that you get an exception instead of `true`.
That is exactly what I claim in the example. So, what is not true?
You are mixing up the use case `passing no value at all` and the use case `passing a variable name` such as foo. The use case we have here in the question is to test if a  variable with this name is defined.
Anyway I have edited my answer and added how to call the function.

Comment: You cannot make any expression with a variable that hasn't been defined yet. That has nothing to do with the way the function is defined; any function body would give you the same result, even `_.noop` which completely ignores its arguments. In fact, so would non function call expressions such as `({})[foo]`. Now try this: `var foo = undefined; isUndefined(foo);`. That will return `true` again.

Comment: Are you saying do use that function, because in these two special cases `isUndefined()` and `var foo = undefined; isUndefined(foo);` it works as expected? It is unclear to me why you seem to ignore the case where the function throws an exception and claim that my answer is wrong.

Comment: I'm not ignoring that case, I'm telling you the exception has nothing to do with the function itself. If you do not declare or define `foo` in advance, JavaScript will throw the same exception for any expression involving `foo`, such as `console.log(foo)`, `foo + 1`, `foo()` or even `foo === undefined`. Even if you define `isUndefined(obj)` as `typeof obj === 'undefined'`, JavaScript will still throw that same exception when you call `isUndefined(foo)`. My point is not about which definition is best, but about the validity of your argument.